# How can i access variables using modules in python3.4

Tags: module, python-3.4

i have written a file name called "Functions.py" and it consists the following code.

```
def foo(x,y):
    global a
    a=42
    x,y=y,x
    b=33
    b=17
    c=100
    print(a,b,x,y)
a,b,x,y = 1,15,3,4
foo(17,4)
print(a,b,x,y)
```

and now, am trying import this function in an another file called "modulepractice.py".

```
import Functions
print(Functions.a)
```

when I execute the "modulepractice.py", the output is coming as

```
42 17 4 7
42 15 3 4
42.
```

my doubt here is am printing only "a" but in output its executing entire Functions file. Could you please say where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because on importing the **Functions** module, your interpreter executes the statements outside the **foo** function i.e.

```
a,b,x,y = 1,15,3,4
foo(17,4)
print(a,b,x,y)
```

So, the first two lines of your output correspond to the call to the **foo function** and the **print** statement respectively.

If you don't want the first two lines of output, wrap those statements into the `if __name__ == "__main__":` block

i.e.

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
      foo(17,4)
      print(a,b,x,y)
```

In this case, those statements will only be called when you directly execute the "Functions.py" module, and not when you import it elsewhere like in the "modulepractice.py" module.